# comparison of intellij vs springs grails IDE

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

What does intellij do that other IDEs dont vis-a-vis grails?  Im trying to decide whether I should renew my license when it comes time.... thanx...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discussing about IDEs is a highly religious task, so the following points are my personal opinion. IntelliJ's advantages are IMHO:

- Debugging works better
- GSP content assist
- DSL awareness
- better refactoring support for Groovy
- Grails project view
- Integrated UML diagramm of domain classes
- synchronisation of dependencies

Comment: none of the other IDES do those things?  Thats a pretty good list.  I wish that there was a way to turn off all the "cannot resolve symbol" errors that one gets whenever a dynamic property is referenced....

Comment: A year or so ago, I got started with IntelliJ since Grails support for Eclipse was rather bad at that time. In the meantime things might have changed, but I'm stick with IntelliJ. The more I use it the more I like it. 
Eclipse seemed to get closer to IntelliJ over the last year, but I have not used it in the last time - so I cannot tell if the list is exclusively for IntelliJ.

Comment: in sizable files do you get a whole bunch of the cannot resolve symbol errors?  I like the injection of services into controllers and whatnot, but it kinda sucks that I cant autocomplete the methods on those services when I do def myService because intellij cant figure out the type...